# web browser's back button is taking me out of JQuery mobile application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, browser

i am using jquery mobile for building a web application with single page concept means my each pages are separate .html files but all javascript and css files are loading in one index.html

for changing page i am using :

```
$.mobile.changePage('home.html', {transition: "none", changeHash: true});
```

but when i am pressing back button of browser, it is exiting the application.

Can anybody suggest me how to implement back button functionality.
thanks in advance.

Comment: just google [html5 ajax history] ....

Comment: When do you press back button? Are you navigating to other pages with changeHash disabled?

Comment: @Omar after changing to other page if i want to come back.. and changeHash is true

Comment: Before hitting back button, when you move from home.html to page2.html is changeHash disabled?

Comment: no, i am using above code for changing all pages

Comment: after page is navigated, url is not changing at all

Comment: if changeHash is enabled, the url will change. By default it's enabled so using `changeHash: true` is useless. Try without it. Which jQM version are you using?